# Android - Pressed / Touched item in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, items, pressed

Is it possible to know in a ListView if a item is pressed / touched (but not clicked) and know which?

I tried with "OnTouchListener" but without success (I can intercept UP and Down events on the ListView but not on the elements).

I tried also "OnItemLongClickListener" but I have to wait when I want information immediately.

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you in advance.

---

Edit (solution) :

I put the following code in my adapter in the item view.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {                
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {               
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

And now, when I touch an item, the picture becomes "image2" and when I do not touch the screen, it returns to "image1".

But there is a problem, if I press an item (the image2 appears well) and I move my finger in the list view and I do not touch the screen, it stays on for the image2, "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP" could not execute.
Do you have any idea how to do that as soon as I do not touch the screen, it must return on image1?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set SetOnTouchListener to item view when your adapter create it.

Comment: It works perfectly! It was so simple .... Thanks!
But now I have another question, I'll edit my question above.

Answer (score 0):

you just try yo  implement the Listener then you can override  the function or  please add your rough work part

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I have another question that I put in my first post.